# JQuery prevAll not affecting element inside of a <span>

Tags: jquery

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E9gTa/)

Take a look at the demo. Why won't prevall affect the `<select>` that is inside of a span? (or, how could I make it work that way?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.test').bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).prevAll().find('select').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).prevAll().find('select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E9gTa/4/)***

Answer (score 0):

Your first `select` is in span and second not in a `span`..i think that's a typo.

The answer assumes the second `select` is also in span

```
$('.test').bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function(event){
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        $(this).prev().find('select').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $(this).prev().find('select').attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the first case the prevAll returns the previous sibling, in this case the span element which is not disabled but not the select element. So the select element is not disabled. In the second case the select element is selected and disabled. To work in the first case you should find the select in the span element.

```
$(this).prevAll().find('select').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because prevAll selects the "siblings" and "select" is not its sibling, "span" is.  So you can use what "thecodeparadox" suggested.